# Starting from three horizontally split windows in Vim, how to have a new window vertically split to the left of all three initial windows?

Tags: vim-windows, split

Let's say we have three windows split horizontally in Vim and we want to have a new window that is split vertically to the left of all three current windows.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem? Is the solution proposed good enough? If so maybe could you accept it. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Create a fourth horizontal split: <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>
2. Move it to the left: <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd><kbd>Shift h</kbd>

Comment: Also look at topleft and botright modifiers.